# Executing an algorithm constantly on slow and fast machine

Tags: algorithms, memory, memory-usage, speed

Is it possible to create an algorithm that will execute at the same rate and speed on faster and slow computers. What i mean is, i have a year 2000 desktop that can run a certain computational algorithm. a hundred years latter, quantum computers have arrived in their full capacity and i want to run the same algorithm. the Quantum computer should never be able to catch up with the slow computer. 
The several ways i can think:

1. Locking the execution of an algorithm to a specific time, but the problem with this is someone could possible alter the ticks in a second, eventually making the execution time very small, hence fastening the execution.
2. Create a function that only uses a fixed amount on memory. for this i don't know how practical it is.

**What could i do to achieve the desired consistency?**

Comment: see [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: In a way you are touching on a really hard problem of critical importance: How can I create an encryption algorithm that will still be safe in a few decades? Current public-key crypto algorithms (e.g. based on integer factorization or elliptic curve problems) are not [quantum-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-quantum_cryptography).

Comment: This is pretty simple: if you want to achieve timing consistency, you need a reliable clock. If there is no such clock available (or the clock can be manipulated), the program cannot make any guarantees about its wall-clock running time.

Answer (score 6):

## No

It's not possible.

The only "solid" solution to achieve the same execution time would be the "literal" approach: Using the language's date/time library to wait for a fixed time before quitting. This is because *the language itself guarantees its correctness*. If Java is still going to be used in the year 3000 on a quantum computer, the Java makers will have the important bits ported and adjusted so that *one second is indeed a second*. However, if I understand correctly, the system is *so* compromised that even a second is not a second anymore.

The other direction you aim to go there - abusing hardware quirks and restrictions as a timer, a bit like [The Story of Mel](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/story-of-mel.html) - is by its very definition tied to a certain set of hardware. Hardware getting faster and/or changing is not just *a potential danger to look out for*. On the contrary, we can say with confidence that *it will most definitely happen*.

### Instructions vs Executions

It makes sense if you think about it like this: A program is just a set of steps for a computer to execute. The steps don't care about how (fast) they are executed. That's completely up to whoever takes the steps and executes them.

Because timing is a thing needed often, there *is* a way (in most programming languages) to say "wait 2 minutes" - but if the instructions are not followed... At that point you actually have a faulty compiler/computer/VM. At that point, timing issues are only one of your smaller problems.